# Is a third party website allowed to post messages on facebook, on behalf of another site?

Tags: facebook, widget, share

So here's my use case:

- A user sees a cool product on a shopping website (sample-shopping-site.com)
- They want to share this product with their friends on facebook
- They however want to pass the information to an intermediary site (a-sharing-app.com - that i'm trying to develop), that posts to facebook on my behalf.

My questions:

1. Is this even allowed by facebook? i.e. can a-sharing-app.com put a widget on sample-shopping-site.com, so that a person visiting sample-shopping-site.com can share on facebook via a-sharing-app.com?
2. If yes, could you point me to helpful bits on the facebook developers API page?

Just want to clarify: the APIs and most questions/examples on the internet point towards sharing directly from sample-shopping-site.com to facebook, by registering sample-shopping-site.com as an App with facebook.

I however want to register a-sharing-app.com as an App, and then putting a widget of a-sharing-app.com on any page (such as sample-shopping-site.com) allows me to share on facebook by passing information to a-sharing-app.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know there is no Facebook guidelines that restrict what you want to achieve, so I may safely say that **yes**, you can create an app so that a person visiting sample-shopping-site.com can share on facebook via a-sharing-app.com . I can even mention a well know service that is doing the same, [Disqus](http://www.disqus.com/).
2. How you can implement this feature is a little up to you but may I suggest what Disqus or apps like it are doing is, they use the [JavaScript API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/) of Facebook to integrate and are mostly enabled within an `iframe` that loads content from their domain. The exchange of information between `sample-shopping-site.com` and `a-sharing-app.com` is done by the JavaScript loader which loads the necessary `iframe` then. The other things you would like to check would be [Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) which you may use for different cases, or you may do it on your own using the [`FB.api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) and make API calls to the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for sharing data.